# Excel VBA to call .exe which is programmed to modify/changes in the caller workbook

Tags: excel, vba, exe

Is it possible to call `.exe` from `VBA` and that `.exe` can manipulate this caller workbook? (such as adding sheet, modify some data).
 How do i achieve this?
 Can `.exe` have an access to the caller workbook?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:
1. Run the VBA-macro and send the path via commandline. The .exe then opens the Workbook and do its thing.
2. And more difficult: The VBA still sends the path / or Workbook name and the exe finds all running excel.exe processes, hooks them up and inspect their Workbooks. If you have found the process with "your" sheet, you can control it via COM.

The second way should be more stable but 1. is also possible, especially if you can save all changes to the workbook and savely quit Excel via VBA. Your Program could simply wait until the file is unlocked and writeable.